# Unix shell script run SQL scripts in parallel

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, parallel-processing, ksh

How do I setup this KornShell (ksh) script to run SQL scripts 2,3 in **parallel** after tst1.sql is done then run tst4.sql after 2,3 are complete? Is this possible?

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
#SET ENVIRONMENT ORACLE

sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst1.sql
sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst2.sql
sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst3.sql
sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst4.sql
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command should run synchronously...

If you start the two last commands as background processes (add & at the end of the command), they will run in parallel.

Do you want the script to wait for the two last processes to be complete before leaving?

Something like this should work:

```
  sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst1.sql
  sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst2.sql &
  pid2=$!
  sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst3.sql &
  pid3=$!
  # pseudo-code:
  # while (`ps -p"$pid2,$pid3" | wc -l` != "1");
  sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst4.sql
```

Comment: Yes. I want to wait. I also want to add another tst4.sql to run after 2,3 are complete. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just concat tst2.sql and tst3.sql into some file (tmp.sql) that you would execute sync after tst1.sql and tst4.sql?
Unless these files are very big (Gb), that is the easiest solution you'll have...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to use sync? No files are very small.

Comment: I meant synchronously. When you run 'sqlplus user1/pw @/home/scripts/tst1.sql', the script doesn't move to the next line before that process is complete...
Why are you trying to run tst2 and tst3 in parallel? ... Do you really want 2 concurrent processes hitting the db?

Comment: need to run 2,3 in parallel to finish job faster then once that's complete, run last sql.

Comment: Can I use wait after I put tst1.sql in the background and then another wait command after 2,3?

Comment: I updated my answer... you just need to figure out the right syntax for the while but this should work.