# sqlplus within a loop - unix

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql, sqlplus

Is there a way send multiple sqlplus commands within a loop but waiting for one to run with success in order for the next one to start ?
Here is a sample of my code. I have tried to add that sleep 15 because the functions that I'm going to execute are taking like 10-20s to run. I want to get rid of that 15s constant and make them run one after the other.

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
   checkUser "$1"
   while read line; do
     sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line
     sleep 15
   done < "$wrapperList"
fi
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was going to send sqlplus commands in parallel. It's just a list of .sql files that will be used in the sqlplus command. Did not tried, that was my first assumption. I'll try and I'll come back with an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction in a `while` loop are done in sequence. It would be equivalent to do like that, using `;` to chain instructions:

```
sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line1 
sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line2
```

**So** you don't need the `sleep 15` here, since the `sqlplus` commands will not be called in parallel. The way you did it already is calling them one after the other.

Nota: It is even better to stop running if first line  did not return correctly, using `&&` to say: run only if previous return code is `0`

```
sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line1 &&\ 
sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line2
```

To have this in the while loop:

```
   checkUser "$1"
   while read line; do
     sqlplus $user/$pass@$server $line
     RET_CODE=$? # check return code, and break if not ok.
     if [ ${RET_CODE} != 0 ]; then
       echo "aborted." ; break
     fi
   done < "$wrapperList"
```

**On the other hand,** When you want to run in parallel, syntax is different, like here: [Unix shell script run SQL scripts in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200727/unix-shell-script-run-sql-scripts-in-parallel)